# error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webautomation

in the code below, I tried to log in to a website using selenium But I get this error selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Thanks in advance

**Code**:

`from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

URL = 'website'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')   
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(URL)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"username"))).send_keys("nocsud")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"value"))).send_keys("noc_sud10")
driver.find_element_by_id("submitDataverify").click()


#-------------------------------------------------------------------
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()
root = soup.find(id='root')
print(root)`

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you to use options.add_argument("interactive") that let you see what's happening in the webpage and where is the code stopped at,
probably one of the elements that you are searching in the DOM are not found
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"username"))).send_keys("nocsud")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"value"))).send_keys("noc_sud10")

try to check if "value" or "username" are ID's or Names

Comment: thank you for your response, so when i changed the argument to interactive, i see the probleme now, it's because chrome see the website as unsafe and the problem now is how can'i bypass the unsafe page

Comment: You should click the advance and click continue to unsafe page, something like that, you can use selenium too.